# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException How to solve

Tags: c#

I can't figure this error out. I know 100% that the path is right, because I have checked.

Error:

> System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: 'Could not find a part of the path 'Projects/CurrentProject/proj_dta/assets/'.'

I haven't tried anything. There isn't much to try.

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, framework.assetsPath());
}

//framework.assetsPath = Projects\CurrentProject\proj_dta\assets
```

It *should* transfer the file to my path. It doesn't.

How do I solve this?

Comment: I suggest you look up the difference between absolute and relative paths.

Comment: I don't get why that would change anything....?

Comment: Does `Projects\CurrentProject\proj_dta\assets` exist inside your project's `bin/debug` or `bin/release` folders?

Comment: bin/debug @Amy.

Answer (score 1):

You'll probably want to ensure that the absolute path is absolutely correct. It will absolutely matter what .NET thinks your current directory is. I would recommend using something like:

```
Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), framework.assetsPath())
```

Your current/working directory could be not what you expect. This will ensure that you can accurately get the absolute path. Hope this helps!

```
if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
    File.Copy(openFileDialog1.FileName, 
              Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), framework.assetsPath()));
}
```